# Mysql : Get comma delimited Output

Tags: mysql, sql, perl, command, delimiter

I am connecting to MySQL server and executing a select statement using Perl backticks. The output of the command is being captured in an array as shown below:

```
my @output = `mysql -u <user> -p<password> -e 'select * from <database_name>.<table_name>' -s`;
```

The -e option gives me tab delimited output with each row on a new line (batch mode) and -s gives minimal output in a non tabular format(silent mode).

**Is there an option in the MySQL command to get a coma delimited output instead of tab delimited ?**

(**NOTE:** I want to avoid concatenating values in the sql query)

Comment: Just convert it to commas after the fact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no obvious option to do this (the options are [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-command-options.html)).  You can change the query to get what you want:

```
select concat_ws(',', col1, col2, . . . )
from <database_name>.<table_name>
```

But this requires listing all the columns (which I personally think is a good thing).  You can also do the substitution after the fact.